# Extending admin template issue

Tags: django, django-templates, django-suit

I'm having an issue extending the admin template for Django-Suit. I have the following directory structure:

`/API/manage.py`,
`/API/appname/` etc.

I've done this before without issues but I think it's because I have it in a subfolder in API?

I have: `/templates/admin/base.html`

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load admin_static %}


<style>
  form-horizontal .inline-related span {
  display: inline-block;
  }
</style>

{% block footer_links %}
  <a href="/docs/" class="icon"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i>Documentation</a>
{% endblock %}
```

But it doesn't seem to be extending properly.

`settings.py`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: You need to call your template base_site.html, otherwise your going to loop... - http://django-suit.readthedocs.org/en/develop/index.html?highlight=base#templates

Comment: @jamesO oops! Fixed that, but doesn't seem to load still.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?